# Query to detect row type basing on the number of the row

Tags: sql, select

I have this table:

[image: My Table]

There are two different types of records: records where the third, fourth and fifth columns are null and records where only the sixth column is null. I need a query (which I will later insert into php code) which, **based on the number of a row**, allows me to detect if it is a record of the first type or of the second type. For example, row 1 --> first type, row 2 --> first type, row 3 --> second type,... Any idea?

Comment: Have a look at the `ROW_NUMBER()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` expression here:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN email_cliente IS NULL
         THEN 1
         WHEN date_inizio IS NULL AND date_fine IS NULL AND id_prodotto IS NULL
         THEN 2 ELSE 3 END AS type
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you don't add tables as screenshots.
This is what you need,replace col values with real names. If there are only two types then you just need one `case` statement to check if 3 columns are `null` or not. If they are not `null` then record is of second type.

```
   select 
    col1,
    col2,
    case when col3 is null and col4 is null and col5 is null then 'second_type' else 'first_type' end
    from table
```

Answer (score 0):

For brevity, you may utilize `coalesce`

```
 select *, case when coalesce (date_inizio, date_fine, id_prodotto) is null then 'type2' 
                else 'type1' end as type
 from your_table;
```